# Multiplying float and integer literals in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm working with VHDL-2002, trying to declare a constant in the following way

```
constant CORDIC_SCALE_FACTOR    :   integer := 0.607252935*(2**COORDS_WIDTH);
```

With `COORDS_WIDTH` being a previously defined generic. However, I'm not being able to perform this multiplication due to types. What I would like to do, is cast `2**COORDS_WIDTH` to a float type, and then cast the result to an integer value (assuming the cast would take the real part of the float and assign it to the integer). How can I accomplish this? I've found resources on the web dealing with this type of conversion but not on literals, this should be easier.

Comment: *"this should be easier."* Welcome to VHDL. If you want an easier life use System Verilog. :-)

Comment: So there is no way to perform this operations between constants?

Comment: I am sure a VHDL expert will give you an answer soon. It is for this sort of things which should be simple, but which are not that, that I try to avoid VHDL as much as possible. You can probably help them by telling which VHDL standard you are using. 2008?

Comment: I'm working with gHDL which only supports partially VHDL 2008, so I'm using 2002

Comment: `error: no function declarations for operator "*"`, it's complaining about the result value, there's no "*"[real, integer return integer] multiplying operator. Dedicated to Oldfart's prejudice against strongly typed languages. Provide a [mcve] with error indication, 4 lines with the declaration for constant COORDS_WIDTH in a packge. The fix  is a type conversion -  `constant CORDIC_SCALE_FACTOR: integer :=  integer(0.607252935 * (2 ** COORDS_WIDTH));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, it was pretty straightfoward. The 'float' type is named 'real'

```
constant CORDIC_SCALE_FACTOR    :   integer := integer(0.607252935*real(2**COORDS_WIDTH));
```

Comment: This would work for COORDS_WIDTH < 31 (The floating point type used for ghdl's REAL is 64 bits with a 36 bit mantissa, but 2 ** 31 is 2147483648 or INTEGER'HIGH + 1, out of range for a universal expression, see IEEE Std 1076-2002 7.5 Universal expressions).